# Is there a software alternative to Mac OS X built in internet sharing services?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, airport

The Internet Sharing feature in Mac OS X (available at the "sharing" System Preferences panel) seems to be somewhat limited, it does not have the ability to use WPA when sharing through AirPort for instance.

Is there a simple software alternative that will use a MacBook Pro built in AirPort card to create a local wi-fi access point?

Comment: Thanks Jon, I appreciate your suggestion - I'll wait a bit more to see if there is any software solution before I accept it as my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X's built in internet connection sharing is not really up to long term use.  Snow Leopard at least has introduced 128 bit WEP compared to Leopard's 40 bit

The best solution is to get a hardware WiFi router - only about $40 and it will give you WPA2.

Comment: There are a variety of routers that let you share a 3G modem. Just one example is this Netgear: http://blogs.techrepublic.com.com/hiner/?p=899

Answer (score -1):

You can have this functionality from the system preferences itself. before enabling the internet sharing just click on it. the details will be show on the right side. tick on airport, and then on the "Airport Options" you can create your own password protected wifi network.

Comment: Yes he knows this - it's what he said in his question. He wants to use WPA not the WEP that OS X has built in.